# The role of std::ws (whitespace) when reading data

Tags: c++, whitespace, getline, stringstream, istringstream

Data saved in my file is (white spaces added at both beginning and end on purpose for this test):

1   2   3

Loading the data using the code below with or without "std::ws" does not cause any difference. So I am confused by the role of "std::ws" as I have seen code using it. Can someone explain a little bit? Thanks!

```
void main ()
{
ifstream inf; 
inf.open ("test.txt"); 

double x=0, y=0, z=0;
string line;

getline(inf, line);
istringstream iss(line);
//Using "std::ws" here does NOT cause any difference
if (!(iss >> std::ws >> x >> y >> z >> std::ws))
{
    cout << "Format error in the line" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << x << y << z << endl;
}
iss.str(std::string ());
iss.clear();

cin.get();

}
```

Comment: Whitespace is removed in the beginning of the extraction by default. If you have `std::ios_base::noskipws` on or are using unformatted input then `std::ws` can be useful.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The flag is called `skipws`; `noskipws` is a manipulator function.

Comment: @0x499602D2: the primary use isn't so much when `std::ios_base::skipws` is disabled but rather with unformatted input which doesn't skip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 12):

The primary use of `std::ws` is when switching between formatted and unformatted input:

- formatted input, i.e., the usual input operators using `in >> value, skip leading whitespace and stop whenever the format is filled
- unformatted input, e.g., `std::getline(in, value)` does **not** skip leading whitespace

For example, when reading an `age` and a `fullname` you might be tempted to read it like this:

```
 int         age(0);
 std::string fullname;
 if (std::cin >> age && std::getline(std::cin, fullname)) { // BEWARE: this is NOT a Good Idea!
     std::cout << "age=" << age << "  fullname='" << fullname << "'\n";
 }
```

However, if I'd enter this information using

```
47
Dietmar Kühl
```

It would print something like this

```
age=47 fullname=''
```

The problem is that the newline following the `47` is still present and immediately fills the `std::getine()` request. As a result you'd rather use this statement to read the data

```
if (std::cin >> age && std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, fullname)) {
    ...
}
```

The use of `std::cin >> std::ws` skips the whitespace, in particular the newline, and carries on reading where the actual content is entered.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid input. Fields should be separated by a known character, either newline or tab, and you go to the next field using `ignore`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: what isn't valid input? The code and input as is are working entirely as expected. If it makes you more comfortable assume the `if()` condition is written as `if (std::cout << "Enter your age: " && std::cin >> age && std::cout << "Enter your full name: " && std::getine(std::cin >> std::ws, fullname)) { ... }`

Comment: I mean, it's a strange program that doesn't care whether an input item appears on a new line or not. Essentially you're using `>> ws` to be sure that newline is treated the same as tab or space. Seems suspect to me.

Comment: If the input is `47 Dietmar Kühl`, then `>> ws` is still needed to remove the leading space. That might be a clearer example.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'd consider it more suspect to skip characters otherwise! For example, if you feel you'd use `std::cin.ignore()` I would start off entering `" \n"` and if you then `ignore()` until the end of the line I'd enter `"47 Dietmar Kühl"` next! Skipping only space, including admittedly, as many newlines as are entered prior to non-whitespace seems a better option when data is potentially entered manually. Of course, if a file is formatted in a specific way, e.g., using JSON or CSV, none of these approaches apply.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: also, formatted input also considers spaces, tabs, and newline as whitespace, i.e., you can enter as may spaces and newline as you want before, e.g., an `int` is read (assuming `std::ios_base::skipws` is set).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking more along the lines of CSV. There's a continuum from flexible command-line inputs to strict network message formats. But, trying to accommodate "tricky" users is a slippery slope. BTW, under `skipws`, your example `" \n47 Dietmar Kühl"` is tolerated. Usually, though, a line-oriented program uses `getline` to extract, re-buffer, and validate that newlines weren't used as ordinary "field separators."

Answer (score 2):

By default, the stream's `skipws` bit is set and whitespace is automatically skipped before each input. If you unset it with `iss >> std::noskipws`, then you'll need `iss >> std::ws` later.

There are also times when whitespace is not automatically skipped. For example, to detect the end of the input, you can use `if ( ( iss >> std::ws ).eof() )`.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

[skipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/) and [noskipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/) are **sticky** but [ws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/ws/) is NOT sticky, so if you want to skip whitespaces with ws you must use it before every operator>>.

Also note that *skipws* and *noskipws* only  apply to formatted input operation performed with operator>> on the stream.
but *ws* applies to both formatted input operation ( using operator>> ) and unformatted input operation (e.g. get, put, putback , .... )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char c;
    istringstream input( "     1test      2test       " );

    input >> skipws;
    c = input.peek();
    //skipws doesn't skip whitespaces in unformatted input
    cout << "After using skipws c = " << c << endl;

    input >> ws;
    c = input.peek();
    cout << "After using ws c = " <<  c << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
After using skipws c =  
After using ws c = 1
```